# Running multiprocess applications from MATLAB

Tags: c++, windows, matlab, multiprocessing, openmp

I've written a multitprocess application in VC++ and tried to execute it with command line arguments with the [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) command from MATLAB. It runs, but only on one core --- any suggestions?

**Update**:In fact, it doesn't even see the second core. I used OpenMP and used `omp_get_max_threads()` and `omp_get_thread_num()` to check and `omp_get_max_threads()` seems to be `1` when I execute the application from MATLAB but it's `2` (as is expected) if I run it from the command window.

**Question**:My task manager reports that CPU usage is close to 100% --- could this mean that the aforementioned API is malfunctioning it's still running as a multiprocess application?

### Confirmation:

I used [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check if there were any differences in the number of threads.

When I call the application from the command window, `1` thread goes to `cmd.exe` and `2` go to my application.

When I call it from MATLAB, `26` threads are for `MATLAB.exe`, `1` for `cmd.exe` and `1` for my application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to contact TMW about this? You may have to sacrifice a chicken in order to get the right kind of representative, but this sounds very much like a problem with Matlab's insides.

Comment: Lol ... well, yeah maybe I'll email somebody. In any case, it's not like OpenCV (which I use extensively) where I can fix a bug and use the fixed version immediately, i.e. even if they fix it I'll have to wait a while!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is how Matlab is affecting your app's behavior, since it's a separate process. I suspect Matlab is modifying environment variables in a manner that affects OMP, maybe because it uses OMP internally, and the process you are spawning from Matlab is inheriting this modified environment.

Do a "set > plain.txt" from the command window where you're launching you app plain, and "system('set > from_matlab.txt')" from within Matlab, and diff the outputs. This will show you the differences in environment variables that Matlab is introducing. When I do this, this appears in the environment inherited from Matlab, but not in the plain command window's environment.

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

That looks like an OpenMP setting related to the function calls in your question. I'll bet your spawned app is seeing that and respecting it.

I don't know why Matlab is setting it. But as a workaround, when you launch the app from Matlab, instead of calling it directly, call a wrapper .bat file that clears the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable, or sets it to a higher number.

Comment: Dude .. +100 if it were possible. Thanks!

Comment: For those who're interested, I wrote a batch file with `set OMP_NUM_THREADS=%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` before executing any commands :)

Comment: D'oh! I should have thought of this myself, since I recently had a problem with environment variables in the terminal "opened" by Matlab for system commands. +1!

Answer (score 1):

Run the command outside of Matlab and see how many cores its using.  There should be no difference running it from within Matlab because its just a call down to the operating system.  IE. equivalent from running on command line.

**EDIT**

Ok odd, what do you get when you call `feature('NumCores')` ?  What version of Matlab are you using?

Does it help to enable this?

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

Comment: It works. I opened a new command window and keyed in the exact command, and it uses both cores.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think that's for MATLAB's own computation. It's set to `Automatic` and `2` at the moment. `feature('NumCores') ` returns `2` as well

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute in MATLAB command-line:

> > setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 4

if you want to use 4 threads.