# MATLAB feature function

Tags: matlab, function

I'm curious where to find a complete description of **FEATURE** function? Which arguments it accepts? No documentation was found. I heard only about `memstats` and `getpid`. Anything else?

```
>> which feature
built-in (undocumented)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Note: A more complete list of features, explanations and references can be found here: [http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function/](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function/)

***feature*** is an entirely undocumented and unsupported Matlab function, and unlike most other undocumented Matlab functions it actually does often change without prior notice between Matlab releases, so be very careful when using this function in your code.

Having said that, several feature options have been reported over the years, mainly on the CSSM forum and also seen in the installed Matlab code base:

***feature*** accepts two arguments: the name of the feature and an optional new value. This is similar to ***get/set*** functions: If only one argument is supplied, Matlab returns the current feature value (like ***get***), otherwise the value is modified (like ***set***).

- ***feature***('usehg2',1) - this apparently relates to a new Handle-Graphics implementation that is currently under development (for the past few releases) - if anyone has any information about HG2 I would love to hear it...
- ***feature***('JavaFigures') - mentioned in propedit.m; [disabled since R2007a](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/268464) when native (non-Java) Matlab figures were disabled.
- ***feature***('NewPrintAPI') - mentioned in \toolbox\matlab\graphics\private\setup.m
- ***feature***('accel’,’on/off’) - see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/76874#196081)
- ***feature***('getpid') - [returns the Matlab process ID](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3L4JU7/) (well, actually the PID of its JVM but that's the same PID as Matlab's). Also see the similar `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getName.char`.
- ***feature***('NumCores') - [returns the number of CPU cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626230/running-multiprocess-applications-from-matlab) seen by Matlab
- ***feature***(memstats, dumpmem, processmem, ...) - multiple online references
- ***feature***('hotlinks') – see toolbox\matlab\helptools\info.m
- ***feature***('UseOldFileDialogs') – see toolbox\matlab\uitools\private\usejavadialog.m
- ***feature***('timing')

  - cpucount = feature('timing','cpucount') – see toolbox\matlab\iofun\tempname.m (several other 2nd arg options)
- ***feature***('DefaultCharacterSet') - see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252869)

And here are a few more references taken from the installed R2010a Matlab code base:

- ***feature***('useGBT2') 
  – *"feature('useGBT2') is only available when Matlab is started with -hgVersion 2 option."* - In /ja/xlate:15419; also see in: clf.m
- ***feature***('COM_ActxProgidCheck',flag) - /help/techdoc/helpsearch/_533.cfs
- ***feature***('TimeSeriesTools',1) - /help/techdoc/helpsearch/_533.cfs
- ***feature***('launch_activation', 'forcecheck') – /toolbox/local/StudentActivationStatus.m
- ***feature***('HGUsingMatlabClasses') – /toolbox/local/hgrc.m, subplot.m, title.m, xlabel.m, ylabel.m, zlabel.m, mesh.m, surf.m, colorbar.m etc. etc.
- ***feature***('EightyColumns',1) - /toolbox/local/matlabrc.m
- ***feature***('GetSharedLibExt') - /toolbox/matlab/audiovideo/private/privateMMReaderPluginSearch.m
- ***feature***('locale') - mlint.m, mtree.m, helpmenufcn.m
- ***feature***('clearjava',1) - javaclasspath.m
- ***feature***('figuretools') – domymenu.m
- ***feature***('getdefaultprinter') – printdlg.m:578
- ***feature***('ShowFigureWindows') – printjob.m, printtables.m, /toolbox/matlab/graphics/private/warnfiguredialog.m
- ***feature***('SearchUDDClassesForHelp') - /toolbox/matlab/helptools/+helpUtils/@HelpProcess/getHelpText.m
- ***feature***('Automationserver') - notebook.m, enableservice.m = ***enableservice***('AutomationServer', true)
- ***feature***('EnableDDE',flag) – enableservice.m = ***enableservice***('DDEServer', true)

The following are OpenGL-related features that are used in ***opengl***.m function:

- ***feature***('openglmode')
- ***feature***('OpenGLLoadStatus')
- ***feature***('UseMesaSoftwareOpenGL',1)- unix only
- ***feature***('usegenericopengl',1)
- ***feature***('getopenglinfo') = ***opengl***('info')
- ***feature***('getopengldata') = ***opengl***('data')
- ***feature***('OpenGLVerbose',1)

Comment: @Yair, thanks a lot for the answer. I hoped you will see this question. I actually looked on your web site and didn't find any information on feature function. Would be cool to see an article there.

Comment: this post is really awesome, +10 if I could!

Comment: @yuk Votes accumulate over time as new users find this question after years.

Comment: @glglgl: Yes, but my comment was almost 2 weeks after the answer. Really great answer should get points quickly. Well, that just was bad time probably. Anyway I'm happy for this answer to get more points with time.

Answer (score 1):

[This MathWorks product support page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html) lists a few other ways FEATURE can be used under [this section about tools for measuring memory usage](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html#_Toc170182661):

```
feature dumpmem
feature processmem
```

Aside from that, I've only been able to find out that it takes up to 2 inputs and returns 1 output:

```
>> nargin(@feature)

ans =

     2

>> nargout(@feature)

ans =

     1
```