# MATLAB: controlling for number core / threads

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Suppose that I have a program that is to be run on a linux machine with 32 cores (64 threads), of which I'm only allowed to use 10 cores (20 threads). So I would like to specify this before I run the program.

I googled and found `maxNumCompThreads` but it doesn't appear to work when I test it on a machine with MATLAB 2016a, core i5 (**2 cores, 4 threads**). That is, I get the same output for `feature('numCores')` when I do any of the following

```
maxNumCompThreads(1)
maxNumCompThreads(2)
maxNumCompThreads(4)
maxNumCompThreads('Automatic')
```

Then I tried `parpool` (each time I closed the current parpool session with `delete(gcp('nocreate'))`). I got an error when running `parpool(4)` (I think I understand why: `parpool` takes in the number of cores and hyper-threading is enabled automatically and the testing machine has just 2 physical cores). So I tested with `parpool(1)` and `parpool(2)`. Again, the output for `feature('numCores')` did **not** change.

**Question**: so what is a right tool for the job for the situation described in the first paragraph above? And is `feature('numCores')` the right monitoring tool to see if the appropriate specification is in effect?

---

The same `feature('numCores')` output I keep referring to above is:

```
MATLAB detected: 2 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 4 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 4 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 2 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.
```

---

**Edit**: when I run `parpool(10)` on the linux machine I got the following error

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... Error using parpo              ol (line 103)
Couldn't interpret output from psname.sh: ""

Error in parpool_test_2016_10_03 (line 3)
parpool(10);
```

Comment: you may have weird results in a computer with 2 cores and 4 treads because you can not use more/less/ `parpool(1)` makes little sense, it is not a parallel pool if it only has 1 core.  No idea eh, just hypothesis

Comment: @AnderBiguri Interesting. I'll see if I can find a way to test it. Will report back.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Please see the edit. `parpool` doesn't even work on the linux machine.

Comment: Weird, it should work on Linux. Also, I think you need to be able to provide a iicense per core, but can't confirm on that.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the right monitoring tool. Look at `feature('numthreads')` instead:

```
>> feature('numcores')
MATLAB detected: 4 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 8 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 8 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 4 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.

ans =    
     4

>> feature('numthreads')    
ans =    
     4

>> maxNumCompThreads(1)    
ans =    
     4

>> feature('numcores')
MATLAB detected: 4 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 8 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 8 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 4 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.

ans =    
     4

>> feature('numthreads')    
ans =    
     1
```

In general, be careful using `feature` as it's undocumented and prone to change without warning. Take a look at [this post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701215/matlab-feature-function) for more information about `feature`.